# python pool.map() and shared array variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a thread pool where each thread should be able to access an array. Unfortunately, that's not working as I thought. That is a minimal code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import multiprocessing

class MyClass():

    shared = []
    l = multiprocessing.Lock()

    def __init__(self):
        with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
            pool.map(self.mythread, range(1,10))

        print(self.shared)


    def mythread(self, param):
        print(param)
        self.l.acquire()
        self.shared.append(param)
        print(self.shared)
        self.l.release()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    instance = MyClass()
```

I expected the last output to contain all numbers, but it doesn't, it's even empty. Furthermore, it seems that I have loss of numbers in the intermediate array states. I'd think that there aren't race conditions possible.
Output:

```
1
[1]
2
[1, 2]
3
[3]
4
[3, 4]
5
[1, 2, 5]
6
[1, 2, 5, 6]
9
7
[1, 2, 5, 6, 9]
[3, 4, 7]
8
[3, 4, 7, 8]
[]
```

Comment: I think you need to use shared memory. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).

Comment: You *are not using a thread pool*, you are using a *process pool* and the processes do not share state. As an aside, that is a list, not an array

Comment: I assume you are aware that `Pool.map` returns the list of values returned by the function, so in your example you could have `def mythread(self, param): return param` and `self.results = pool.map(self.mythread, range(1,10))` and be done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is incorrect. It would work using multiple **threads**, since they share memory, but multiple *processes* do not share memory! The memory is copied to the child processes so each one has its own copy of the "shared" array and the main process has the original copy which is never touched.

The `multiprocessing` module does [have some facilities to handle shared state](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) however be aware that shared objects are *way* slower than normal python objects. It's often easier instead to make the child processes completely independent and let the main process recombine the outputs in the end.

In your case you can use the [`Manager`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-managers) object to instantiate a shared list:

```
import multiprocessing

class MyClass():

    shared = []
    l = multiprocessing.Lock()

    def __init__(self):
        with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager, multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
            self.shared = manager.list([])
            pool.map(self.mythread, range(1,10))

        print(self.shared)


    def mythread(self, param):
        print(param)
        self.l.acquire()
        self.shared.append(param)
        print(self.shared)
        self.l.release()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    instance = MyClass()
```

But this is probably going to be faster:

```
import multiprocessing

class MyClass():


    def __init__(self):
        with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
            results = pool.map(self.mythread, range(1,10))
            final_result = [x for res in results for x in res]
        print(final_result)


    def mythread(self, param):
        print(param)
        # assume that this might return more than one value
        return [param, ...]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    instance = MyClass()
```

BTW: in the case where the functin applied with `map` has a result that is independent from the other subprocesses and it only have one result then simply using `map` is going to return the list of values you want.